# dynamic el value in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to use a value such as post-header-id-23 for an el id value. I was just going to use jQuery like this:

```
$('#post-header-id-' + this.model.id).after(compiled_template);
```

but it looks like the events don't get wired up. Is there a way to fix that so that jQuery selectors don't inhibit normal selectors. Alternatively, it looks like something like:

```
el: $('#post-header-id' + this.model.id ),
```

but how would I set this up in the render function? Or am I doing something else wrong?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing here is that you have to decide *when* is the right time to decide what "el" is; unfortunately you can't just give Backbone a selector and expect it to magically stay up to date.

So, bearing that in mind, if "render" is the right time to set your el (and usually either initialize or render is the right spot), you just need to use Backbone's (somewhat new-ish) `setElement` function:

```
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        this.setElement($('#post-header-id' + this.model.id));
        return this;
    }
})
```

Comment: hmm... total noob question but would el then not be a factor. I am basically compiling a template so I would think I'd need to assign it somewhere.

Comment: If you don't set el (via setElement or by providing `el: something`) Backbone will automatically create a new (class-less, id-less, empty) div element for the view's el.  You can absolutely use that to do something like `this.$el.html(resultsOfTemplate)`, without specifying an el, but then at some point you're going to have to append that view's el to some element on the page (if you want to see it, which you probably do ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

As of 0.9.9 version

> When declaring a View, options, el and tagName may now be defined as
>   functions, if you want their values to be determined at runtime.

Something like this should do it:

```
id: function() {
  return '#post-header-id' + this.model.id
}
```